# Display UIViewRepresentable as a navigationBarItem in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I can get a button to display in the navigationbaritems in SwiftUI no problem.

I want to display a wrapped `UIKit` view in the same.

This is a minimal example of a real problem. I want a 100 * 4 UIView displayed as a trailing navigationbaritems.

Here is my code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("stack overflow test")
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: TestView())
            .navigationTitle("Navigation")
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


struct TestView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 4))
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {

    }
}
```

Right now nothing displays in the top-right hand corner of the navigation bar. Why might this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting frame inside the `UIViewRepresentable`, set frame in `navigationBarItems` `ContentView`

Tested in Xcode 12.3 with iOS 14.3

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("stack overflow test")
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: TestView().frame(width: 100, height: 4)) //< === Here
            .navigationTitle("Navigation")
        }

    }
}


struct TestView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView() //< === Remove From Here
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {

    }
}
```

**Note :**

From iOS 14.5 [navigationBarItems](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbaritems(leading:trailing:)) is deprecated. Use [ToolbarItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbaritem)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("stack overflow test")
            }
            .toolbar { //< === Here
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    TestView().frame(width: 100, height: 4)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Navigation")
        }
        
    }
}
```

[image]